Obtener Video Stream de una camara v380 con python
Tengo una cámara de seguridad v380, quiero con Python y cv2 capturar el video en vivo de esa cámara, no conozco sus protocolos ni nada sobre la cámara.
La cámara tiene un QR y este es su contenido "V380^77154481^AWT3610E^3^2^1909170002^20231108114801"
La cámara está en la LAN con la IP "192.168.0.101" y tiene dos puertos abiertos
8800 Sun Web Server Admin Service
9800 WebDav Source Port
Esa es la única información que tengo sobre la cámara.
¡Por favor, ayúdenme, gracias!

Podrias activar RTSP en la cámara siguiendo estos pasos y luego deberías poder leer los frames de la camara con opencv

Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.
